# What does "give all those Mudbloods a kick from me" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Ron's—or rather, Crabbe's—face was contorted with fury. "What's up with you, Crabbe?" snapped Malfoy.
>
> "Stomach ache," Ron grunted.
>
> "Well, go up to the hospital wing and ***give all those Mudbloods a kick
>   from me***," said Malfoy, snickering.
>
> "You know, I'm surprised the Daily Prophet hasn't reported all these
>   attacks yet," ... ...

According to [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kick):

> If something ***gives you a kick***, it makes you feel very excited or very happy for a short period of time.

But it doesn't look fit for this context. Maybe the phrase just takes its literal meaning here. Does the phrase have a special meaning? What does it truly mean?

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He literally wants Ron to kick the Mudbloods in the hospital. The *"from me"* part means he's metaphorically sending the kick like a letter, via someone else (Ron, or Crabbe, as he thinks).

The author is not using the phrase "give a kick" as its own idiom, but as a literal instruction in the form of "Give [direct object] an [indirect object] from me." This is commonly used in expressions of well-wishing or greeting to someone who is not present, for example

> Give him a hug from me.

The idea is this: the next time the "giver" sees the person in question, they will perform the action and say that it comes "from" the first person, because they could not be there themselves. It is not usually used for negative sentiments, but it can be, as shown here.